# Changing background css with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the website http://scoopsgelato.co.uk/, when their webpage loads the background image at the top of the page changes after around 10seconds.

I want to know how to do a basic version of this. Code that sets the background-image property in the css to cycle through images.

I tried for a few hours to get it myself but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were looking for something simple, here is one solution at least for some inline CSS.

```
var imgArry = ["http://dummyimage.com/200x200/cf90cf/555770.png&text=pic+1", "http://dummyimage.com/200x200/c99011/555770.png&text=pic+2", "http://dummyimage.com/200x200/cc5601/555770.png&text=pic+3"];
function backgroundImageSlider(elem, imgs, speed){
   var index = 0;
   var timer = setInterval(function(){
      elem.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgs[index] + ")";
      index++
      if(index == imgs.length){
         index = 0;
      }
   }, speed);
}

backgroundImageSlider(document.getElementById("imageDiv"), imgArry, 10000);
```

Here is a JSFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/o3zhwhdp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Set a timeout to a function that changes the image:

```js
    var imageSrcs=['//google.com/favicon.ico', '//w3schools.com/favicon.ico', '//stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico'];
    var currentImage=0;
    setInterval(function() {
      if (currentImage<3) {
        currentImage++;
      }
      else {
        currentImage=0;
      }
      console.log(currentImage);
      document.getElementById('image').src=imageSrcs[currentImage];
    }, 10000);
```

```html
<image id="image" src="//google.com/favicon.ico">
```

That probably isn't the fastest/shortest way to do it, but it certainly is simple enough to understand the dynamics of it.